# Significato di "paccare" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Dieci giorni dopo cominciarono le sue lezioni. Il tiepido e onnisciabordante febbraio regalava giorni di un sole che tingeva di vari gialli le facciate dell'Istituto. Dei trentacinque iscritti, dopo il primo mese di lezione ne restarono trentaquattro e questo – come disse il direttore **paccando** la spalla di Felice – costituiva un bel risultato.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "paccare" in questo passo. Dal contesto, ho pensato che significasse dare dei colpetti sulla spalla (derivato da "pacca"?), ma non sono riuscita a ottenere conferma su nessun vocabolario. Sul [supplemento del 2009 al *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_Pagina_599.jpg) ho trovato questo verbo col significato di "pomiciare", ma questo non sembra avere molto senso nel contesto del testo. Qualcuno di voi ne sa qualcosa? Potrebbe trattarsi di un uso toscano?

Comment: Non conosco questo Luti, ma comincio ad avere l'impressione che il suo italiano sia un po' troppo liberale per te! A me personalmente non dispiace, in certi casi, una stortura (o libertà) simpatica e intelligente, ma questo *paccando* lo digerisco male.

Comment: Anch'io trovo che spesso faccia un uso molto personale della lingua...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: A me piace molto: leggendo questo libro sto imparando molte cose interessanti sulla mia città. Sì, lo stile è un po' una sfida per me: a me piacciono le sfide, però (per esempio, dopo aver letto *L'Inferno*, adesso sto leggendo anche *Il Purgatorio*, molto lentamente, però). Lo stile un po' "troppo piano" di molti scrittori attuali invece mi annoia. Non capisco cosa vuoi dire con "liberale per me": una domanda sulla lingua non è una recriminazione, anzi, è qualcosa che mi ha incuriosita.

Comment: Adesso me n'accogo che appare sul GDLI come dialettalismo anche [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000322.jpg) (scusate, ma le ricerche sul GDLI sono a volte un po' complicate). Questo dizionario afferma che si tratta di una voce d'area centrale, in particolare lucchese, e fa alcune citazioni di Pasolini.

Comment: E ho visto anche che in [questo dizionario](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=PACCARE100) appare col significato di "toccare, tastare" (che non è lo stesso che "dare una pacca" però), ma penso che qualche volta si sia detto che non abbia molta credibilità (è così?).

Comment: @Charo, "troppo liberale per te" non è una critica a te, e neppure a Luti. Ho pensato, forse sbagliando, che se ami e vuoi approfondire l'Italiano, allora uno scrittore meno dialettale andrebbe meglio. Però anche i contributi dialettali sono interessanti, tutto è interessante! È solo questione di gusti. Quindi chiedo scusa: probabilmente quel "paccando" mi ha irritato e mi sono sbottonato troppo...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:     Quando si è arrivato al livello C1, si deve affrontare l'italiano "reale" e questo include l'italiano regionale (infatti, l'italiano regionale è un componente importante nell'esame di livello C1, perlomeno in quello che ho fatto io: ancora mi ricordo di un maledetto audio sul presepe napoletano difficilissimo da capire...).

Answer (score 2):

Pomiciare è il significato che ha a Roma e dintorni, al nord paccare significa dare buca, non presentarsi, o anche fregare o raggirare in una compravendita tra privati ("gli ho dato i soldi ma mi ha paccato").
In questo caso però viene utilizzato impropriamente con il significato di "dando delle pacche"

Comment: Attento agli accenti! ;)

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Alessandro, e grazie della risposta! Il verbo ha il significato indicato sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11510/significato-di-paccare-in-questo-contesto#comment27316_11510), che riporta la definizione del Nieri. Cioè, come hai anche indicato tu, quello di "dare delle pacche", che adesso mi sembra sia il senso che ha nel brano riportato nella domanda.

Comment: L'unico è che, nell'altra risposta, si mette in dubio che "spalla" possa essere usato come oggetto diretto del verbo e invece, secondo il GDLI, si tratta di un verbo transitivo e, grazie agli esempi di Pasolini, possiamo vedere che l'oggetto diretto è appunto la parte del corpo o l'oggetto su cui si danno le pacche o che si palpa.

Answer (score 1):

Credo che la tua intuizione sul fatto che si tratti di un "toscanismo" sia corretta come anche la supposta derivazione da "pacca", come sembra confermare il [*Vocabolario lucchese*](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=z4w0AQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=paccare) di [Ildefonso Neri](https://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-n/idelfonso-nieri/). 
La cosa un po' strana, a mio avviso, è
la codificazione di "spalla" come oggetto diretto e non un obliquo locativo "paccando Felice sulla spalla".

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=z4w0AQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=paccare

Comment: Potresti includerlo nel tuo post? Preferirei una risposta che non dia la sensazione di qualcosa di inventato.

Comment: Il libro è il [*Vocabolario lucchese*](https://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-n/idelfonso-nieri/) di Idelfonso Nieri.

Comment: Vedi l'[uso che ne fa Pasolini](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000322.jpg): è "paccare le chiappe di quella donna", non "paccare quella donna sulle chiappe".